# Strange problem while uploading large files

Tags: php, file-upload, ini-set

I am having a strange problem while uploading large files in PHP.

In php.ini, `max_execution_time` is set to 30, `post_max_size` is set to 32M, `upload_max_filesize` is set to 32M. When I tried to upload a file of size 40.2 MB, it don't show any error. The `$_FILES` variable has the value `array(0) { }` and `$_FILES['userfile']` shows `NULL`.

If the file size is more than the value set in php.ini, then it should return the error message

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE, Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

But it's not showing any error either (as `$_FILES` is an empty array). I am clueless why this is happening.

When I change in php.ini and set post_max_size is set to 64M, `upload_max_filesize` is set to 64M, then it works fine. So, I decided to use the following code, instead of changing php.ini file.

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

I even tried to increase `max_execution_time`. Still, I am having the same problem. `ini_set()` is not working here.

Comment: I'm not sure why the UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE error was not being raised, but I can say that setting upload_max_filesize or post_max_size with ini_set has no affect because these cannot be set an runtime, according to this ini list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To have the 40 MB file fail with upload error, you have to increase the post_max_size, if you exceed the value of that variable, you get an empty $_FILES array. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

> If the size of post data is greater
>   than post_max_size, the $_POST and
>   $_FILES superglobals are empty.

Also, ini_set() is not working there because two of the variables you are trying to change    are [PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) and thus need to be changed in php.ini or in .htaccess or httpd.conf. You should try the 40MB file with, for example, [these settings in .htaccess](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Comment: Best answer, except you cannot set upload_max_filesize and post_max_size using ini_set(), only via .conf or .ini files.

Comment: Actually this is stupid ! wqhat if i don't want to allow my sites guests to upload more than 2MB (cuz of the flood they can make) but if they are members to upload up to 150MB ????

Comment: @Ronan: In that case you have to create two separate directories, one for guest uploads, and the other for member uploads.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more setting you may need to look at, Apache's `LimitRequestBody`.

If the file exceeds that, the upload may get blocked before it even reaches PHP.

[Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: This is also a good point. I never knew it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

> ini_set() is not working here.

The values you are trying to change with `ini_set()`, except for `max_execution_time`, cannot be changed with `ini_set()`.
In the [list of php.ini directives](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), they are reported to be of type `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, which means (as explained in [Where a configuration setting may be set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)) that they can changed in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf. Configuration settings that can be changed with `ini_set()` are the ones marked as `PHP_INI_USER`.

Comment: I want to mark this as accepted answer, but Stack Overflow allows to mark only one answer as accepted answer, which I already marked.

Comment: @Debiprasad: It's not possible to have two accepted answers; you should deselect the previously selected, before to select another answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

FOR SERVER:

In cPanel search for php, You will find "Select PHP version" under Software.
Software -> Select PHP Version -> Switch to Php Options -> Change Value -> save.

FOR LOCAL:

Find the PHP ini(configuration settings) file in php folder under xampp.
Change 
`post_max_size = 40M` and `upload_max_filesize = 40M`